# Why the constructor function didn't executed?

Tags: java

Why constructor function RegisterProxy() didn't executed when we called the "  R response = proxy.CallAPISync(request);" ?

```
public class SoaCaller {
    private static  RegisterProxy proxy = new RegisterProxy();  ;
    public static <T, R> R CallAPISyn(T request){
        R response = proxy.CallAPISync(request);
        return response;
    }
}

public class RegisterProxy {
   private static HashMap<String, BaseSoaImplement> cache = new HashMap<>();
    public RegisterProxy(){
        try {
                  cache.put(GetHotelStaticInfoRequestType.class.getName(), new GetHotelStaticInfoImpl());
  } 
catch (Exception ex){
         ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex));
        }
}
```

Comment: Because that doesn't create a new instance. The constructor was called when `SoaCaller` was loaded.

Comment: constructors will only be called at the time of object creation.

Comment: My only explanation is that it has been called before.

Comment: I edit the original questions. finally I found the I got the exception "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument zone is null or whitespace " when called the code line: cache.put(GetHotelStaticInfoRequestType.class.getName(), new GetHotelStaticInfoImpl());
However I don't know why tthat exception happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new RegisterProxy();` is *only* ran the first time a *classloader* encounters the  class `SoaCaller`.

That could be far earlier than the calling of `CallAPISyn`